# Does not contain a definition for 'file_src' October CMS

Tags: octobercms-plugins

I am currently working at October CMS plugin development, I have a problem with file upload. I put the `fileupload` type to `file_src`.  When I go to to resource it shows an error like this :

[image]

```
model/resource
    fields:
        name:
            label: Name
            type: text
            required: true
        file_src:
            label: Upload
            type: fileupload
        grade_id:
            label: Grade
            type: dropdown
            emptyOption: Select
            showSearch: true
        subject_id:
            label: Subject
            type: dropdown
            emptyOption: Select
            showSearch: true
        type_id:
            label: Type
            type: dropdown
            emptyOption: Select
            showSearch: true
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it! We must use $attachOne or $attachMany relation on model

I added following code in Resource.php in models

```
public $attachOne = [
    'file_src' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

thats it its working now!

Answer (score 1):

> Define the current module the selected control is a file. Mean your
>   current selected control is as a file and you does not define in your
>   module that time the backend has confused.
>
> Solution:

```
public $attachOne = [
        'profile_pic' => \System\Models\File::class
    ];
```